# L'expression « opérateurs sociaux » ?

Tags: expressions

Comment peut-on *comprendre* l'expression « opérateurs sociaux » dans ce contexte:

> Les femmes sont un des objets de l'échange matrimonial et non un des
>   partenaires entre lesquels il a lieu. Il en résulte un pouvoir global
>   des hommes sur les femmes. L'essentiel, c'est la transformation des
>   femmes en véritables opérateurs sociaux par le moyen desquels se fixe
>   la Loi (prohibition de l'inceste), se constituent des rapports sociaux
>   primaires (parenté et alliance) et la première forme du pouvoir
>   (capacité reconnue d'effectuer l'allocation des épouses).

Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce contexte, il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté. L'opérateur social est celui qui opère sur le social, celui qui exerce une certaine influence ou qui est au moins considéré comme un acteur du milieu social.

L'extrait fourni semble évoquer une culture dans laquelle les femmes sont, ou étaient jusque récemment, uniquement des éléments subissant le social. L'exemple de l'échange matrimonial sous-entend clairement les mariages arrangés.

Or le texte met en avant la transformation **vers** des *opérateurs sociaux*. Le texte présente donc une évolution de ce statut de passivité vers un domaine plus actif où la femme peut *opérer* et non subir.

On peut confirmer cette interprétation dans la suite de l'exemple. Les femmes, une fois devenues des opérateurs sociaux, apportent à cette société des avantages telle la prohibition de l'inceste.

En résumé, les opérateurs sociaux sont ici les **femmes transformées**, c'est-à-dire les femmes qui ne sont plus simplement des objets mais bien des êtres humains.

Par exemple, dans les sociétés européennes les femmes sont des opérateurs sociaux. Dans certaines sociétés asiatiques, les femmes sont considérées comme propriété de leur père puis de leur époux et ne sont donc pas des opérateurs sociaux.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax vous avez tout à fait raison. En vous lisant c'est une interprétation tout à fait plausible. Venant moi-même d'une société souhaitant l'égalité homme-femmes, j'ai interprété cet extrait comme positif. Sans lire l'entièreté du texte ni avoir des explications sur sa provenance c'est difficile de déterminer exactement la nature de l'extrait. Mais dans les deux cas je pense que la définition d'opérateur social fournie fonctionne (qu'elle soit vue positivement ou non).

Comment: Je salue sincèrement votre idéalisme ! Voir aussi mon [commentaire](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18368/lexpression-se-disent#comment34744_18368) pour un lien vers le texte entier. Merci !