# Que veut dire l'expression « se dire par » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Que veut dire l'expression « se disent » dans ce contexte (*[Le sexuel et le social. Lecture anthropologique](http://classiques.uqac.ca/contemporains/balandier_georges/sexuel_et_social/sexuel_et_social_texte.html)* de Georges Balandier dans les *Cahiers internationaux de sociologie*, vol. 76, janvier-juin 1984, pp. 5-19):

> la femme adultère relevait d'un véritable châtiment : elle était exposée nue, alors que la nudité féminine est scandale et malédiction ; son corps nu pouvait être livré à la morsure des fourmis ; plus encore, elle pouvait être mutilée sexuellement par ablation du clitoris et exaspération de la plaie. Son corps et son sexe devenaient le « lieu » de la sanction publique. Ayant mis en jeu l'ordre social, elle en était spectaculairement retirée et soumise à une dé-socialisation dramatique, avant de lui être restituée. La loi et l'ordre **se disent par le sexe**.

Answer (score 1):

> SE DIRE : Être employé oralement (terme, expression) :  Cela ne se dit plus.

La loi et l'ordre s'expriment, se manifestent au travers de l'encadrement des pratiques sexuelles ; on peut comprendre la loi, et l'ordre qu'elle encadre, au travers de la compréhension de la place qu'à la sexualité dans la société.

- Le 'langage social' (qui utilise d'autres média que les mots) de la sexualité *dit* ce qu'est la loi et l'ordre.